# Jquery selector: getting all select boxes except multiple ones

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to select all select boxes but multiple select boxes in document. I tried:

```
$('select').not('[multiple]').hide();
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

Definition of a select box:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Definition of a multiple select box:

```
<select multiple>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to say `i am trying to select all selectboxes but multiple select boxes in document.`

Comment: Your code is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/58Chx/

Comment: Try <select multiple="multiple">, that is the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close:

```
$('select:not(select[multiple])').hide();
```

Or:

```
$('select').not('select[multiple]').hide();
```

Comment: @ayhan That link shows exactly the opposite: `:not()` is faster in virtually every case. But, I've posted both versions.